# isset using mixed variable with string literal

Tags: php

How would I check if the variable `label_$value` exists?

E.g:

```
<?php foreach($status_values as $value => $label){ ?>
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" <?php if($status == $value){ echo ' checked="checked"'; }?> />
    <?php echo (isset("label_{$value}")) ? "label_{$value}" : $label; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

This gives error: *Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"'* for the isset

But I dont get any syntax error when I have:

```
<?php echo ("label_{$value}") ? "label_{$value}" : $label; ?>
```

So I want to:

1. Check if the variable exists: `$label_foo`
2. use the default `$label`

Comment: But you don't get any syntax error when you have what?

Comment: Your $value variable doesn't contain the value, it contains the key of the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to use variable variables. use

```
<?php
$label_test = "Hello";
$value = "test";
echo (isset(${"label_{$value}"})) ? "label_{$value}" : $label;
?>
```

Comment: perfect thanks, didn't realise the isset requires the extra syntax

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you compile the variable name. Try `isset(${"label_$value"});`